Javascript Only ESLint 'HTMLElement' is not defined no-undef error?
Not a Typescript Question
I've asked this question once already at it was closed saying that it is already answered here:
ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined in TypeScript
Please note that this is not a typescript project, so the typescript answer does not fit.
Here's the question again.
For the source files in this project this ESLint configuration creates these errors.

/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/src/hello-world.component.js
   7:42  error  'HTMLElement' is not defined     no-undef
  52:3   error  'customElements' is not defined  no-undef

/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/src/hello-world.component.spec.js
  3:1  error  'suite' is not defined  no-undef
  4:3  error  'test' is not defined   no-undef

✖ 4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)

How do we switch these off so that ESLint allows suite, test, HTMLElement, and customElements?
Here are the source files for reference:
eslint.config.js
import eslint from "@eslint/js";

export default [
    // apply recommended rules to JS files
    {
        files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
        rules: eslint.configs.recommended.rules
    },
    {
        ignores: ["rollup.config.js", "web-test-runner.config.js"]
    }
]

src/hello-world.component.js
/**
 *  @category WebComponent
 *
 * Hello World Web Component
 * that renders a greeting.
 */
export class HelloWorldComponent extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['name'];
    }
  
    /**
     * The name to greet
     * @defaultValue World
     */
    name = 'World';
    something
    /**
     * Initializes the name property to `World`.
     */
    constructor() {
      super();
      //    this.name = 'World';
    }
  
    /**
     * Sets the component inner
     * html to the greeting.
     */
    connectedCallback() {
      this.textContent = `Hello ${this.name}!`;
    }
  
    //========================================
    // attribute change callback
    //========================================
    attributeChangedCallback(
      property,
      oldValue,
      newValue
    ) {
      if (oldValue === newValue) return;
      switch (property) {
        case 'name':
          this.name = newValue;
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error(`Unhandled attribute: ${property}`);
      }
    }
  }
  customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorldComponent);

src/hello-world.component.spec.js
import {expect, fixture, html} from '@open-wc/testing';

suite('hello-world.component tests', () => {
  test('fixture instantiation', async () => {
    const el = (await fixture(
      html`<hello-world></hello-world> `
    ));
    expect(el).not.to.equal(null);
    //    expect(true).to.equal(false);
  });
});


There's an eslint answer at the other question. Does browser: true in the .eslintrc.js not work for you?

How about the other answer to that question, which is about ESLint?

OK - one solution is to add global comments like this.
This will fix the test linting errors.
/*global suite*/
/*global test*/

And these comments fixes the globals in the component.
/*global HTMLElement*/
/*global customElements*/


Another way to fix both the component and component spec linting errors it is to add ...globals.browser and ...globals.mocha to eslint.config.js.  First install globals with npm i -D globals.
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";

export default [
    // apply recommended rules to JS files
    
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.mocha
            }
        }
    },
    {

        files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
        rules: eslint.configs.recommended.rules
    },
    {
        ignores: ["rollup.config.js", "web-test-runner.config.js", "src/index.bundle.js"]
    }
]


